# The value of the formula calculation results do not correspond to the figure

Tags: numerical-integration

Original link:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318375689_Mode_conversion_efficiency_to_Laguerre-Gaussian_OAM_modes_using_spiral_phase_optics
[image]
[image]

My purpose is to reproduce the above figure.

The formula is as follows: when $l=L,N\rightarrow \infty$

$$
\left| \varPhi _{\text{l}\nu} \right|^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}}\exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\nu -\nu _0}{\sigma} \right) ^2 \right] 
$$
$$
\times \left| \frac{-i}{l}\frac{\nu _0}{\nu _0-\nu}\left[ \exp \left( i2\pi \left( l-l\frac{\nu}{\nu _0} \right) \right) -1 \right] \right|^2d\nu 
$$

To correspond to the variables within the figure, a further simplification is performed:
$$
Laser\ Bandwidth=x=2\sqrt{2\ln 2}\sigma \Rightarrow \sigma =\frac{x}{2\sqrt{2\ln 2}}
$$
$$
\nu _0=\frac{c}{\lambda _0}=\frac{3\times 10^{17}}{\lambda _0}
$$
Finally ($l=1$):
$$
\left| \varPhi _{\text{l}\nu} \right|^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{x/\left( 2\sqrt{2\ln 2} \right) \sqrt{2\pi}}}\exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\nu -\left( 3\times 10^{17}/\lambda _0 \right)}{x/\left( 2\sqrt{2\ln 2} \right)} \right) ^2 \right] 
$$
$$
\times \left| -i\frac{1}{1-\nu /\left( 3\times 10^{17}/\lambda _0 \right)}\left[ \exp \left( i2\pi \left( 1-\frac{\nu}{3\times 10^{17}/\lambda _0} \right) \right) -1 \right] \right|^2d\nu 
$$

```
f[x_?NumericQ, \[Lambda]0_?NumericQ] := 
  1/(4 Pi^2)
    Norm@NIntegrate[
     Exp[-1/2 ((v - (3 10^17/\[Lambda]0))/(x/(2 Sqrt[2 Log[2]])))^2]/(
      x/(2 Sqrt[2 Log[2]]) Sqrt[2 Pi])
       Abs[-I 1/(
         1 - v/(3 10^17/\[Lambda]0)) (Exp[
            I 2 Pi (1 - v/(3 10^17/\[Lambda]0))] - 
           1)]^2, {v, -Infinity, 
      Infinity}];(*1/4Pi^2 is normalized constant*)

Plot[f[x, 400], {x, 0.001, 200}]
```

[image]

But the calculated result does not match the picture at all, I want to know what my problem is?

Comment: My first thought is that your units do not match. You put $c$ in $\rm{m/s}$ but $\lambda$ in $\mathrm{nm}$. Also, I think a message is generated when you run the code, so you should include it in the question.

Comment: Also, increase the precision with `NIntegrate[..., WorkingPrecision -> 30]`.

Comment: I have corrected the units, but there is still a problem.

Comment: Please look at this partial answer: 
``Clear["Global`*"]; Φ[x_?NumericQ, λ0_?NumericQ] := With[{ν0 = 1/λ0, σ = x/(2 Sqrt[2 Log[2]])}, 1/(4 π^2 σ Sqrt[2 π]) NIntegrate[E^(-((ν - ν0)^2/(2 σ^2))) Abs[-I*(ν0/(ν0 - ν)) (Exp[2 I π (1 - ν/ν0)] - 1)]^2, {ν, ν0 - 10 σ, ν0 + 10 σ}] // Chop]; λ0 = {400, 532, 800, 1064}; Plot[Evaluate[Φ[x, #] & /@ λ0], {x, 0, 0.002}, PlotLegends -> λ0]`` Something is still wrong because the curves do not match properly.

Comment: First, note that you do not need to integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ because the major part of the integrand is around $\nu_0$. Second, I think there is something missing in your derivation. $\mathrm{FWHM}$ and $\sigma$ are in the frequency domain, yet on the plot, the $x$ axis is in the wavelength domain!

Comment: Also it looks like there is a nonintegrable pole at ν0.

Comment: @Domen Thank you very much for your answer, maybe there is something wrong with my derivation or understanding, so I have added the original text to the question.

Comment: @Richardo., I've actually found and read the reference myself. I might try again today :)

Comment: ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main problems in your code.

#### 1. Conversion between $\Delta \nu$ and $\Delta \lambda$

The $\mathrm{FWHM}$ and corresponding $\sigma$ in $|\Phi_{\ell,\nu}|^2$ are in bandwidths of the *frequency*. However, the plot shows the bandwidth of the *wavelength*. The conversion between the two is **not** simply $\Delta \nu = c /\Delta \lambda$ but<sup>1</sup>

$$\Delta \nu = c \frac{\Delta \lambda}{\lambda^2}.$$

#### 2. Numerical convergence of `NIntegrate`

You work with units, the numerical value of $c$ is unfortunately very high, and your integrand is very concentrated around $\nu_0$. All of these lead to troubles with convergence of the integration. The easiest solution is to integrate only around the bulk part of your integrand, namely $\nu \in [\nu_0 - \xi \sigma, \nu_0 + \xi \sigma]$ where $\xi$ is some reasonably small<sup>2</sup> number (eg. $\xi = 10$).

#### 3. Units

You had $c$ in $\mathrm{m/s}$ but $\lambda$ in $\mathrm{nm}$ without proper conversion. You have to either match the units or work with dimensionless quantities (eg. $c=1$ and then $\lambda$ and $\Delta \lambda$ can directly have numerical values in $\mathrm{nm}$).

```
Clear["Global`*"];

c = 3*^8;
Φ[Δλ_?NumericQ, λ0_?NumericQ, ξ_ : 10] := 
  With[{ν0 = c/λ0, σ = c Δλ/(2 Sqrt[2 Log[2]] λ0^2)}, 
   1/(4 π^2 σ Sqrt[2 π]) NIntegrate[
      E^(-((ν - ν0)^2/(2 σ^2))) Abs[-I*(ν0/(ν0 - ν)) (Exp[2 I π (1 - ν/ν0)] - 1)]^2, 
    {ν, ν0 - ξ σ, ν0 + ξ σ}]];

λ0s = {400, 532, 800, 1064}; 

Plot[Evaluate[Table[Φ[Δλ*10^-9, λ0*10^-9], {λ0, λ0s}]], {Δλ, 0, 200}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[λ0s, 
  LegendLabel -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(λ\), \(0\)]\)"], 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Δλ [nm]", "normalized |Φ\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(|\), \(2\)]\)"}]
```

[image: Plot]

---

<sup>1</sup> You obtain the relationship with proper differentiation: $$\nu = c/\lambda \implies \Delta \nu = |(\partial \nu/\partial \lambda)| \Delta \lambda = c\Delta \lambda/\lambda^2.$$
<sup>2</sup> The choice of $\xi$ depends on your precision goals.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you.